# PHP get process creation time?

Tags: php, process, count, win32com

I have a (sample) php code as follows :

```
$name_Proc = "chrome.exe";
$wmi = new COM('winmgmts://'); 
$processes = $wmi->ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name ='".$name_Proc."'");
```

I used it to count the process with following code ,

```
 $array = array();
foreach($processes as $process){ 
         array_push($array,$process->ProcessId);
}
$count_Process = count($array);
return $count_Process;
```

Now, the real thing, i now need the process creation time, it is possible using VBScript with following code :

```
    strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'notepad.exe'")

For Each objProcess in colProcessList
    Wscript.Echo objProcess.CreationDate
Next
```

Now, if i was wondering how would i implement this in my PHP script!

Any clues?

Comment: Every time someone uses COM from PHP, they should be forced to stick a hot fork in their eye.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it would be so nice of you if you tell me its alternative here? Do you? Oh well you can just comment i think..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, sorry everyone, just looked it now got it! I figured it out. Here's the code, hope it might help someone in future :)

```
foreach ($processes as $process) {
print $process->CreationDate;
}
```

This piece of code is used, the complete code is as below:

```
function processMade($pid) {
$name_Proc = "9052";
$wmi = new COM('winmgmts://'); 
$processes = $wmi->ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId ='".$name_Proc."'"); 
$array = array();
foreach ($processes as $process) {
array_push($array,print $process->CreationDate);
}
return $array;
}
```

Or simply use this :

```
 $name_Proc = "9052"; //this is the PID, if you want it by name than change the ProcessId = '".$name_Proc."'" in the 4th line.
    $wmi = new COM('winmgmts://'); 
    $processes = $wmi->ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId ='".$name_Proc."'"); 
    $array = array();
    foreach ($processes as $process) {
    array_push($array,print $process->CreationDate);
    }
```

Best,

Ahsan

Comment: so in 4 minutes you *very suddenly* figured out the solution and also posted an answer? interesting...

Comment: Thoughts have no time to tell!